# How to read JsonResponse in php

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

How to get id from here

```
JsonResponse {#457 ▼
  #data: "{"bill":{"id":11,"invoice_no":"9m36r9_1459170388239"}}"
  #callback: null
}
```

I am getting this output from this laravel code

```
return Response::json($response);
```

I tried `json_decode` but not worked here, a blank output is coming.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What did you try to `json_decode()`?

Comment: Where do you want to show that data?

Comment: I am able to get data in js by ajax but here I am trying to get in laravel/php to generate pdf

Comment: decode it first then it will return an array, so you can access it.

Comment: Where's the other code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try like this

```
$jsonResponse = Response::json([
        'id' => 1,
        'test' => 'test'
    ]);

$content = $jsonResponse->getContent();
$array = json_decode($content, true);
$id = $array['id']
```

Comment: Thanks for _getContent()_

Answer (score 5):

This works for me, using getData(). Laravel 5.7.

```
$jsonResponse = Response::json([
    'id' => 1,
    'test' => 'test'
]);
$content = $jsonResponse->getData();
$id = $content->id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it working for me:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: {
      ...
   },
   success: function (data) {
       alert(data.bill.id)       
   },
   error: function (err) {

   }

});
```

Tell me if this not work.

Comment: Are you sure it works it won't work until you add `dataType:'json'` or use `JSON.parse` in success;

Comment: I'm sure, btw, this my response `return response()->json($data);`